# \fill doesn't get displayed in addition to a \node in tikzpicture-environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

The pdf-file contains a simple tree with the information on a lecture series.
With the following code I want to add some semi-transparent ellipses to cover the topics adressed in a specific lecture.
The display of the pdf-file works completly fine, but the \fill seem to do nothing. No warning, no error message and no displayed ellipse.

Anyone got an idea, what I´m missing here?

```
\documentclass[german, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{array}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (baum) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=.8\textheight]{orientierungsrahmennrw.pdf}};
        \fill[green!50, opacity=0.5] (-1,0, -0.5) ellipse (1.7em and 1.7em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance
Tristan

Comment: Please provide an example that people can use to see the issue. We can not run it as posted, as the image is not available (you can use `example-image` which is generally available for tests) and your question asks about `\hfill` but there is no `\hfill` in the code shown.

Comment: sorry - wrote \hfill, instead of \fill.

Comment: still can not run the example as posted.

Comment: here is the file: https://uni-wuppertal.sciebo.de/s/OY3LBoVGk2vQKtF

Comment: If I use the height=66m as in the posted answer with your image [i get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHDq9.png)

Answer (score 2):

We haven't your images, so I tested your MWE with  `example-image-duck` which is available at each LaTeX installation. Result of test is expected:

[image]

That ellipse (which is actually circle) is better visible, the color is full saturated:

```
\documentclass[german, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (baum) {\includegraphics[height=66mm]{example-image-duck}};
\fill[green, opacity=0.5] (-1,0, -0.5) ellipse (1.7em and 1.7em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you see, your problem is not possible to reproduce with your document example.

**Addendum:**
Using your image, for which you provide link in comment, above MWE also works. Unfortunately image is `.png` and very poor quality. Rezultat compilation of your MWE is similar as before:

[image]

So it is unclear, what you doing.

Comment: Whats the best way to provide my pdf-file that is included as a picture? With the duck example, Its working fine with me also.

Comment: @TrizZm4ster, the used ways seems to be only way to include image for your purpose. i did several pdf file tests, all works fine. What is going wrong in your document we cant say anything. You may provide your pdf image, that we can make tests with it.

Comment: Heres the file: https://uni-wuppertal.sciebo.de/s/OY3LBoVGk2vQKtF